# How is VaR calculated for forward contracts accounting for European put options?

Tags: black-scholes, monte-carlo, value-at-risk, forward, put

My initial idea is to create profit and loss using an equation like this:
\begin{align}
       P\&L = & \text{European Put P&L} + \text{Forward P&L}\\
       P\&L = & [(K-S_T)^+ - \text{Premium}] \cdot{} \text{N Put Contracts} + \\
           & [(S_T - K) - \text{Contract Price}] \cdot \text{N Forward Contracts}\\
\end{align}
Where $S_T$ is the underlying spot at maturity, $K$ is the strike price of the option or agreed-upon delivery price for the forward, $T$ is the time to maturity, and $S_T$ is derived from simulated forward prices from Monte Carlo Simulations and converted to spot via the BSM.

After obtaining a select forward price from an MC Simulation, we follow the BSM model. The forward value of the stock is:

$$F(t_0,T')=\mathbb{E}[S(T')]=e^{r(T'-t_0)}S_0$$

Where $T'$ is the contract maturity. We get the Stock value $S_0$ as a function of the forward value and the discount factor:

$$S_0=F(t_0,T')e^{-r(T'-t_0)}$$

Supposing that $t_0=0$, we get: $S_0=F(t_0,T')e^{-r T'}$.

The Black-Scholes formula based on the underlying stock is:

$$\text{P} = Ke^{-rT}N(-d_2) - S_0 N(-d_2)$$

With:

$$d_2=\frac{ln \left( \frac{S_0}{K} \right)+rT+0.5\sigma^2T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$$

Now, we substitute $F(t_0,T')e^{-r T'}$ for $S_0$ in the above to get:

\begin{align}
       \text{Put Premium } = & Ke^{-rT}N(-d_2) - F_e^{-rT'-T} \cdot N(-d_2)\\
                  d_2 = & \frac{\ln\left(\frac{Fe^{-rT'}}{K}\right)+(r-\sigma{}^2/2)T}{\sigma{}\sqrt{T}}
\end{align}

After calculating P&L for thousands of simulations, I can calculate VaR.

So, I have historical forward prices. Theoretically, I should be able to simulate forward prices, get their spot and European put prices, and calculate profit and loss, then just do a simulated historical VaR calculation. However, I'm not sure about the parameters that I need to pick for the BSM model—volatility, strike prices, number of put contracts, etc. I was thinking about going forward with the volatility as a static historical annual volatility.

I'm not sure if I'm completely wrong or just overthinking it. Maybe I can somehow simulate European put options separately, the forward prices separately, and somehow combine the VaRs. But I'm not sure what assumptions to simulatenously make for both of those processes if I did that either.

Comment: Hi Kyle, which volatility surface do you use? SVI or something else? What kind of put option do you model? American or European or some other option? Would you mind to specify your question a bit or tell a bit more what you have tried so far?

Comment: @T123J Hello, thank you for the comment. I added clarification in the post above. Hope it helps. I'm not too familiar with volatility surfaces though.